# navigating to multiple views dynamically from the sameview - Survey app

Tags: android

I wanted to develop a survey app, which contains a single view and the contents of the view should change dynamically based on the questions type.It has two buttons "back" and "next", when i click "next" it should move to next question and clicking "prev" button it should take us to previous question.How to achieve it in android ?

Answer (score 0):

Use fragments.  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Create multiple layouts inside single xml and then u can  display only one page in layout rest hide .and. Use.  Different IDs for all the page so that u can hide properly